# How do I pull geometries from tidycensus?

Tags: r, dplyr, tidyverse, tidycensus

I am trying to pull geometries from `tidycensus` but keep running into errors.

I enter the following code:

```
### Load packages

library(tidycensus)
library(dplyr)
library(tidyverse)

### Install api key

census_api_key("<mykey>")

### Pull data

cook<-get_acs(geography = "tract",variables = c(medincome = "B06011_001"),year=2018,survey = "acs5",state = "IL",
              county = "Cook",geometry = T)
```

But I receive the following output and error:

```
Getting data from the 2014-2018 5-year ACS
Using FIPS code '17' for state 'IL'
Using FIPS code '031' for 'Cook County'
Error: All columns in a tibble must be vectors.
x Column `geometry` is a `sfc_MULTIPOLYGON/sfc` object.
Run `rlang::last_error()` to see where the error occurred.
```

I follow the prompt and run `rlang::last_error()` and get:

```
<error/tibble_error_column_scalar_type>
All columns in a tibble must be vectors.
x Column `geometry` is a `sfc_MULTIPOLYGON/sfc` object.
Backtrace:
  1. tidycensus::get_acs(...)
  9. dplyr:::right_join.data.frame(geom, dat2, by = "GEOID")
 12. dplyr::tbl_df(x)
 14. tibble:::as_tibble.data.frame(data, .name_repair = "check_unique")
 15. tibble:::lst_to_tibble(unclass(x), .rows, .name_repair)
 16. tibble:::check_valid_cols(x)
Run `rlang::last_trace()` to see the full context.
```

I follow the prompt and run `rlang::last_trace()` and get:

```
<error/tibble_error_column_scalar_type>
All columns in a tibble must be vectors.
x Column `geometry` is a `sfc_MULTIPOLYGON/sfc` object.
Backtrace:
     x
  1. \-tidycensus::get_acs(...)
  2.   +-right_join(geom, dat2, by = "GEOID") %>% st_as_sf()
  3.   | \-base::eval(lhs, parent, parent)
  4.   |   \-base::eval(lhs, parent, parent)
  5.   +-dplyr::right_join(geom, dat2, by = "GEOID")
  6.   +-sf:::right_join.sf(geom, dat2, by = "GEOID")
  7.   | \-sf:::sf_join(NextMethod(), attr(x, "sf_column"))
  8.   +-base::NextMethod()
  9.   \-dplyr:::right_join.data.frame(geom, dat2, by = "GEOID")
 10.     +-base::as.data.frame(...)
 11.     +-dplyr::right_join(tbl_df(x), y, by = by, copy = copy, ...)
 12.     \-dplyr::tbl_df(x)
 13.       +-tibble::as_tibble(data, .name_repair = "check_unique")
 14.       \-tibble:::as_tibble.data.frame(data, .name_repair = "check_unique")
 15.         \-tibble:::lst_to_tibble(unclass(x), .rows, .name_repair)
 16.           \-tibble:::check_valid_cols(x)
```

The function `get_acs()` works fine when `geometry=F`. I'm not sure where to go from here. Any ideas?

Comment: make sure all your packages (dplyr, tibble, tidycensus) are up to date and try again?

Comment: I tried that and it did not solve the problem.

Comment: huh. works on my machine, with tidycensus 0.9.6, dplyr 0.8.5, and tibble 3.0.0. clean your environment, reset the session?

Comment: I had to update my `sf` package and it worked. Thanks for the help!